# ngx-bootstrap Tooltip - Not Dynamic Position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I have a tooltip controlled by ngx-bootstrap, rolling over an icon, a tooltip appears on the top of the icon.

This tooltip looks good if I maximize browsers, but if I minimize them a bit, the tooltip overlaps the icon, that I cannot click on the icon anymore likes the screenshot below:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<span id="appCancelIcon" class="close-circle_red" tooltip="Cancel Changes" container="body"></span>
```

This tooltip is dynamic position, top and left values are different based on positions of icons.

I tried to edit in CSS likes below, then the tooltip became a static position.  It doesn't matter where icons are, tooltips show in the same position.

```
.tooltip.top {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

My question is How to make tooltips still have dynamic position and won't overlap icons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML code, along with tooltip, add **placement** property also.

```html
<span id="appCancelIcon" class="close-circle_red" tooltip="Cancel Changes" placement="bottom" container="body"></span>
```

and then, adjust the css of tooltip.

```css
::ng-deep{
  .bs-tooltip-bottom{
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
}
```

You can also change the placement to "top" and adjust the css of ".bs-tooltip-top" accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `adaptivePosition="false"` it may help you.

Not sure but I faced similar issue and it works for me!

All the best!